# How to prevent Time Machine from backing up while certain app is open

Tags: time-machine

For some reason, InDesign and Time Machine don't play well on my MacBook Pro. Whenever Time Machine starts backing up or prepares backups, I get frequent Beach Balls in InDesign. This might be due to a quite poor WiFi-connection, which I unfortunately cannot fix. My current workflow sees me disabling Time Machine when I use InDesign, and re-enabling it afterwards; however, as you can imagine, I frequently forget one of those things. Thus, I'd welcome a solution where Time Machine just doesn't do its thing while InDesign is running. As there are - as far as I understand – certain conditions, under which Time Machine is prevented from running, I was hoping that there could be some kind of low-level solution (messing with configuration files etc.) I could try? Thanks!

Comment: I would first determine whether this is "normal for InDesign", and if not, fix the problem so that you can continue to backup. What version of ID and MacOS? (And what Mac?) InDesign shouldn't make the WiFi different. It's possible that TM is trying to backup the $ temp files that ID creates, at the same time as ID is writing to them, but generally TM can cope with files in use. You could try excluding ID support files in user Library from the backup.

Comment: This seems to be sort of a known issue: https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/indesign-crashing-lagging-while-running-with-time-machine/m-p/11554453 I'm using InDesign 2021 and macOS 10.15.7